# How can Antlr4 extract interesting parts from a large file

Tags: antlr4

I have the following Antlr4 grammar.

```
grammar Paradox;

paradox:
  kvPair+;

kvPair
  : atom '=' atom
  | atom '=' scope
  | scope
  ;

scope
  : '{' (paradox|atom+)? '}'
  ;

atom
  : STRING
  | NUMBER
  | ID (':' ID)?
  ;

STRING
  : '"' (~'"')*? '"'  ;

ID : [0-9a-zA-Z_]+ ;

NUMBER
    : '-'?[0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?
    ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

The file is 20 MB, looks like this

```
version="Boulle v1.9.1"
version_control_revision=31493
name="泰布理同胞体"
date="2269.02.09"
planet= { ... }
...
country = {
    0 = {
        ...
        name="USA"
        ...
        food_surplus=3.598
        ...
    }
    1 = {
        ...
        name="ENG"
        ...
        food_surplus=2.001
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

`...` means omitted lines by me. The actual file has valid grammar there.

Say I only need to know the number of countries, and for each country, record its name and food_surplus.

Currently what I do is

```cs
ICharStream cstream = CharStreams.fromstring(input);
ITokenSource lexer = new ParadoxLexer(cstream);
ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new ParadoxParser(tokens);
// find kvPair with key "country".
// Then .ChildCount is the number of country,
// find kvPair with key "name" to get the name of the country.
```

This approach works, but the drawback is that it consumes as large as 1GB memory when it's running. Notice I'm not using and don't know how to use visitor pattern or listener pattern.

I understand the large memory consumption is because of the ..., the lines I omitted, which can be millions of lines. Antlr is building parse tree for these uninterested things.

How do I reduce the memory consumption?

Answer (score 2):

A parser is not the right tool for such kind of processing, as it is supposed to validate all the input it gets. That's the main/primary goal of a parser per se. If you are only interested in parts of your input then split it first by other means (e.g. search for certain delimiters) and only feed the interesting parts to your parser.

### Update:

By request: the ANTLR4 docs [have a short description](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/listeners.md) for listeners/visitors, to be used with a parse tree generated by a parser run. In order to use a listener during parsing you just need to [register your listener](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.java#L346) (which is exactly like the one used after parsing):

```
JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);
MyListener extractor = new MyListener(parser);
parser.addParseListener(extractor);
JavaParser.CompilationUnitContext tree = parser.compilationUnit(); // parse a compilationUnit
```

Comment: Strings can contain brackets, and \" is used to escape the string delimiters. If I need to write my own code, these corner cases make it complicated. Do you have any suggestion on handling these cases?

Comment: Right, my idea only works if you have a delimiter which can easily be found in the input stream. If that's not the case you probably have to apply a more complex solution (e.g. tokenizing the input first and picking an input range from the generated tokens for your parser). That requires, however, that your input is fully tokenizable, that is, all input can be represented by tokens, which do not overlap (e.g. value combinations in skippable content do not appear in important content).

Comment: Can I set build parse tree to false by default, while reenable for interested nodes? I don't know how to do.

Comment: Sure, enabling/disabling parse tree generation can be switched on demand, by setting `parser.buildParseTree = false;` (the exact call depends on the runtime platform).

Comment: Can you give an example? My experiments seem to indicate if buildParseTree = false, visitor and listener pattern don't work.

Comment: Right, if you use a listener or visitor after the fact it needs the parse tree as that's what is traversed. However, you can just set a listener before running the parser to get notified about visited rules (similar to a SAX parser).

Comment: See my edit, but keep in mind this is not part of the original question. If you need more assistance wrt. parse trees, listeners etc. start a new question.